# ./camera_i2c: cannot open 5.0: No such file

Tags: gpio, camera

I am trying to connect an Arducam 8mp syncronized stereo camera to a RP4. While setting it up according to the guide (https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/synchronized-stereo-camera-hat/arducam-8mp-synchronized-stereo-camera-bundle-kit-sku-b0298r-troubleshooting/), I keep getting the error:

`./camera-i2c: 155: ./camera-i2c: cannot open 5.0: No such file`

`./camera-i2c: 155: ./camera-i2c: [[: not found`

The `camera-i2c` script is located under /home/pi, where im also working and the rpi3-gpiovirtbuf is also there which can be found by the used comand (see picture below for input and output). What do I have to do so that it can find this file?

[image]

Comment: These are not files. Seems to be an issue in (or before) line 155 in that bash script. I would open an issue on github: https://github.com/ArduCAM/MIPI_Camera/issues

Comment: Found a working solution, thank you for the tip Dirk. On line 155 i uncommented the if statement ```if [[ "$version" < "5.0" ]]; then``` and the entire else statement (lines 157-159) and now it works.